# PsExec Access Denied on remote computer

Tags: windows, windows-10, active-directory, psexec

I am trying to start a program remotely using PsExec, however when attempting to connect I get the error message "Access is denied.".

Most of the answers found here on SU or on other forums haven't worked. Most of the time its due to user account calling PsExec is unable to access the Admin$ share, of which I can access without a problem.

Both the calling account and remote account are on the same domain

```
PsExec.exe \\remotePcName -u Domain\Username -p Password -i -d cmd /c "" something.bat
```

I've tried running PsExec as the domain administrator account and my domain account which is also a domain admin.

The stranger thing is that it was working up until recently, but I am unaware of any changes on the domain or with windows that would otherwise prevent it.

Comment: Does the account in question have _local_ admin rights on the remote machine? (Since Domain Admin is for managing AD, not machines, it's common practice to remove local admin rights from them.) Have you tried specifying the username in the Kerberos UPN format as `username@domain.tld`? Does access to the service manager via `sc \\remotePc query` work? And, have you considered WinRM via `winrs -r:\\remotePc` (or via PSRemoting) as a built-in alternative?

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons for PsExec failing with the error message
"Access is denied". Below I listed some (hopefully most) of them:

- PsExec is not Run as Administrator (try a local administrator if
  the domain one doesn't work).
- Ensure that your user account has access to `\\$machine\ADMIN$`.
- Check if the firewall on the remote computer is blocking
  your access.

More advice is to be found in the post
[PSEXEC, access denied errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828432/psexec-access-denied-errors).
I reproduce below the
[answer by james](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14103682/165358):

> 1. as someone mentioned add this reg key, and then restart the computer :
>
>    ```
>    reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\system /v LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
>    ```
>
>    Read [this knowledge base
>    article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/947232) to learn what
>    this does and why it is needed
> 2. Disable firewall (note - this will leave you with out any firewall protection)
>
>    ```
>    netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state off
>    ```
> 3. if target user has a blank PW and you don't want to add one, run on target:
>
>    ```
>    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa] "LimitBlankPasswordUse"=dword:00000000
>    ```
> 4. This didn't work for me, but i have read it did for others in a few places, on target execute:
>
>    > Start -> Run -> secpol.msc -> Local Policies -> Security Options -> Network Access: Sharing > and security model for local accounts >
>    > Classic – local users authenticate as themselves
>
>    if already in 'Classic':
>
>    > move to "Guest only - .." run from elevated command prompt gpupdate \force move back to 'Classic - .." again run from elevated command
>    > prompt gpupdate \force
> 5. This one solved my issue:
>
>    > run on target from elevated command prompt "net use" look at ouput chart and for shares listed in remote column there (i only deleted the
>    > disconnected ones - you can try them all) run "net use [remote path
>    > from before list] /delete" then run 'net use \target\Admin$
>    > /user:[user name]' enter prompt password request (if empty PW just
>    > press enter), viola should work.

Some more advice can be found in the other answers on the linked post.

Comment: Have you looked into any of the suggestions above?

Comment: "Most of the answers found here on SU or on other forums haven't worked"

Comment: In that case there's no point in asking your question, if no known remedy has worked for you. So what do you expect of us?